# How to convince a developer that inline and mixed JavaScript/PHP code is bad?

Tags: javascript, php

This code snippet is from a teammate of mine, his title is "Full Stack Developer". He mostly writes PHP. I found this code at the end of a .php file and asked him to move it to a separate .js file for testability, maintainability... just some best practices.

He denied, he actually said this code is "extremely simple" and refactoring just makes it more complicated without any benefits. He talked about KISS, about performance...

[image]

Comment: I'd recommend posting this over at programmers.stackexchange.com, it seems more on-topic there.

Comment: Can I move it or have to rewrite this post? Thanks.

Comment: Opinion based or not, that style of code (writing js with php) is awful.

Comment: I moved it as suggested, thanks. http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/288421/how-to-convince-a-developer-that-inline-and-mixed-javascript-php-code-is-bad

Comment: Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise. I would suggest that you find a development forum (perhaps [quora](http://www.quora.com/Computer-Programming)?) to work out generalities.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just tell him story about [Spaghetti code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaghetti_code), [design patterns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_design_pattern), etc. and then fire him.

Comment: Don't forget the [flying spaghetti monster](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flying_Spaghetti_Monster) which invented spaghetti code :)